# Mean # tosses to reject null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size

If I keep flipping a biased coin, my confidence that the coin is not fair will build (on average) with each toss. If I continue this process indefinitely, I will end up concluding that the coin is not fair. (i.e. reject the null $H_0:(p=0.5$), at a 1% sig level)

What is an appropriate test to use that describes this process? (namely, a process where my confidence in the null changes over time). I do not know how biased it is, so I can't just decide in advance that eg 30 trials is enough.

(And if such a test exists, could we compute the mean number of trials needed, to reject at 5% sig?)

Comment: The answer depends on the details of the test you use.  Which one(s) do you have in mind?

Comment: Ah good point. I imaged using a simple test of proportions (sample proportion vs Null Hypothesis proportion), but I'm actually open to any method that's tractable.

The kind of application would be "If I replace a fair coin with an unfair one (with probability of heads being p1), how long (on average) will it take someone to realise this?"

Comment: The most fundamental distinction to be aware of is that repeatedly applying a test like the binomial test of proportions, *which is intended for a random sample of predetermined size,* is invalid. You appear to be describing a sequential test of some sort, but we need to ascertain whether that's the case.

Comment: Yes, a sequential test would be appropriate. What could be suitable in this case?

Comment: Well, now it gets complicated.  Some tests, such as the Sequential Binomial Probability Ratio Test, require you to specify the power at which they will be run.  The greater the power you need, the greater the mean number of tosses will be.  To avoid conflicting answers, please consider editing your post so that it states explicitly what test you are asking about.